# Replacing the existing Project on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed a Java Web application on Google Cloud platform and have purchased a domain and SSL Certificate from GoDaddy.com.

Its a simple application with a login page and a registration, where a specific(only one user) will have login credentials and post login will submit a form which will be saved in google DATASTORE in Google Cloud Platform(GCP).

I have two queries here :

1)

My application works perfectly,on my machine and even few machines around my home (as i have verified in few cyber centres around) but not at a client place located in different city(150 miles away). I'm not sure,as the client is not running any firewall or any browser plugin, as i have not visited the client place yet.

The call is as below.

Domain purchased from godaddy.com is : "**ABC.in**"
App engine project linked to this domain is : "**web-abc**"

If we hit "ABC.in" in browser it will in-turn call "web-abc.appspot.com".
in the background.Now though the login page loads,the client complains that the next subsequent pages does not load and page becomes blank.But for me in my system it works perfectly,as i can see the updated DATASTORE in GCP.

2)

Once i configure my DNS at GoDaddy.com, i'm unable to make any changes to the project hosted on GCP app engine.So i decided to create a new project and host it on the GCP. But GCP app engine page does not show any option to replace a project as it showed me during my first project setup.

I need to replace project "web-abc" linked to "ABC.in" with "web-pqr".

Please Please help...!

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second query you can just rest your CNAME record in the GODADDY DNS configuration and add the web-pqr reqq. That should work. Rest of the question< i really don't get it. Please share some error message or the screenshot when you try make change to your exiting project.